# Suitable networking protocols for low latency, one-packet messaging

Tags: http, networking, tcp, https, latency

What would be some suitable transport and application layer protocols for a secure payments network where low latency is a key goal?

Here "low latency" means completing an encrypted transaction as fast as is possible given current networking technology, taking much less than one second for the networking bits, all round trips included, not counting human activity. Assume distances of no more than 1,000 miles (1609 km).

In this scenario, messages would usually occupy a single packet of perhaps 1 KB size. It would be slightly bursty in that discrete transactions would trigger brief bursts of traffic, while most clients most of the time would be idle.

Reliability is important, where "reliability" means something like 99% of sessions succeed on the first attempt. At this stage reliability *doesn't* refer to its common usage in describing networking protocols as "reliable" – I wouldn't want to bias the process by smuggling in implementation details like reliability at the transport layer...

At the transport layer, I'm aware of TCP, UDP, SCTP, Reliable UDP, DCCP, and things I don't understand yet like Enet.

At the application layer, I'm aware of HTTPS/TLS/HTTP/2, and QUIC / HTTP/3. (I think QUIC might collapse some layers and simplify things, so maybe it also encompasses the transport layer.)

What would you recommend? Do you think UDP can meet the reliability target under typical internet conditions? Perhaps UDP wrapped in application layer reliability, such as QUIC? Or do you think TCP can hit the latency target?

Does your recommendation change if we assume a private network where any protocol can get though middle boxes and such? I'm intrigued by SCTP – any thoughts there?

Thanks much.

Comment: Send the same packet 15 times by UDP? You can't really get lower latency than that.

Comment: 15 times? You mean to make it super reliable or something?

Comment: 15 might be overkill, but just in case one of them gets randomly dropped. That's the lowest latency you'll get. Everything else involves waiting for a round trip, and some protocols need several round trips.

Comment: And then you can detect whether the server actually got the message, and retry if it didn't, but at that point, your lowest possible latency goal has been completely destroyed because you had to wait for a timeout.

Comment: @user253751 that misses the reliability part. Every sent packet is indenpend. You still have no way to ensure it got there.

Comment: try https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PedroRodrigues By the time you have detected that the server didn't get the packet, "low latency" is right out the window.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues also that is completely the wrong stack exchange. Don't post it there.

Comment: You are also limited by packet size here. Not all local links are created equal. You have to fit everything required by the client well within a 1500 byte frame. Perhaps even cutting it down to 500 bytes or less. Each byte increases the chance of corruption, and the chance that a link will break the packet into two, further increasing the chances of delayed/dropped packets.

Comment: Your talking about payments there. First use something reliable, so based on TCP. Next if you want to optimize this you need to make us a drawing of the list of exchange, so we an eventually suggest stuff with less round trips. The rest is more about network administration. Finally, why do you need less than one second ? Peoples aren't using the payment bouton as they're navitgating through the HNQ of StackExchange.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I already asked on Network Engineering and they closed it, so I asked it here. Successfully asking a question on Stack is remarkably difficult.

Answer (score 2):

For *lowest possible latency* you don't have a chance to have a back-and-forth conversation with the server. You can send a packet and that's it. To increase reliability, you can send 10 or 20 packets and hope that at least one doesn't get dropped.

Anything else is not low latency. *All* protocols - including QUIC, TCP, SCTP, Enet, and your own custom one - detect dropped packets by timing out and retrying. That means you need to wait for the timeout. That means there is extra latency.

But, then you said 1 second. 1 second is actually not very low. You can send a packet all the way around the world 3 times in 1 second. So it comes down to setting a short retry timeout and minimizing round trips.

In the worst case, where your packet has to go all the way around the world, extra round trips are very noticeable. They take about 0.3 seconds each.
But you said the maximum distance is about 1000 miles. It doesn't take 0.3 seconds for a packet to go 1000 miles and back (usually), so you could use a low timeout, like 100ms. That would let the program time out and resend the packet several times before hitting the one second limit. The server needs to be prepared to handle duplicate packets, of course, in case the packet takes more than 100ms to get there and back.

Note that it doesn't matter whether you implement this with TCP or QUIC or UDP - the fundamentals are the same. The only reasons you might not be able to use TCP are that the operating system doesn't let you set the timeout that low, or that the extra round trip for the handshake is unacceptable.